# is this correct usage of dbcontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC4, EF web application.

I have a data access class ("db_calls") that has all my methods for data access.

In each of my controllers I instantiate this class once with:

```
private db_calls dbcalls = new db_calls();
```

This "db_calls" class instantiates the dbcontext in order to work with the data like so:

```
private MyContext db = new MyContext ();
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Everytime I access a db_calls method from my controller e.g. db_calls.getrecord() does it instantiate the class **again** or just once per controller?
2. When I hit another controller, does it get rid of the previous instantiation of db_calls and start another one?
3. Similarly, does the db_calls class itself instantiate the context each time for a method or does it do it only once?

My concern is that I am going to have a load of objects floating about that I dont need.

Comment: One question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whenever you use the "new" keyword a new object is created in memory.

1. Only once per controller if instantiation code is written outside methods.
2. Yes
3. Yes, whenever you creAte a new db_calls it will create a new context.

Also I think your case is not too much non-optimized.

Comment: thank you. simple and easy to understand. I realise it is not optimised. this is my first app, so functional first, optimal later.